# ConcurrentModificationException como proceder?

Tags: java, lista

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private void houveAlteracao(Long id) {
        try {
            Objeto objeto = service.find(id);
            objeto.setEventos(JsfUtils.ordenarListaEventosPorHora(objeto.getEventos()));
            Objeto obj = popularObjeto(objeto.getCodigo());
            obj.setEventos(JsfUtils.ordenarListaEventosPorHora(obj.getEventos()));
            if (obj.getEventos().size() > objeto.getEventos().size()) {
                for (Evento ev : obj.getEventos()) {
                    for (Evento e : objeto.getEventos()) {
                        if (!ev.getHorario().equals(e.getHorario())) {
                            objeto.getEventos().add(ev);
                            ev.setObjeto(objeto);
                            if (ev.getDestino() != null) {
                                ev.getDestino().setEvento(ev);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                service.update(objeto);
                pesquisar();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Está ocorrendo o erro:

> 13:18:23,335 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>
> 13:18:23,336 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
>
> 13:18:23,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)

Eu li que o erro ocorre por conta de se alterar uma lista em iteração, alguém sabe como posso fazer pra resolver ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a interface `Iterator<T>` para iterar a lista que deseja modificar.

Ao invés de fazer `for (Evento e : objeto.getEventos()) { }`, faça:

```
Iterator<Evento> iterator = objeto.getEventos().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Evento e = iterator.next(); //se quiser usar a iteração atual
    iterator.add(ev);
}
```

Isso adiciona o objeto `ev` ao `iterator` durante a iteração.

---

Se quiser que o item seja adicionado de fato na lista (para usar depois de que sair dos laços de repetição, por exemplo), **acho** que você precisa adicionar esses itens em uma "lista temporária" durante as iterações e depois fazer um `addAll()` na lista original. Não tenho certeza se o `Iterator` faz o *bind* de volta para a lista quando é modificado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou testar mais tarde. Uma dúvida, não posso fazer nada na lista durante a iteração(alterar,adicionar,remover) como eu estava fazendo ?

Comment: Tranquilo! ;). Não. você não pode mexer na lista, mesmo utilizando o `Iterator`. Ele se baseia na sua lista original. Se mexer vai lançar a mesma `Exception`

Comment: Se não pode mexer na lista porque vai lançar a mesma Exception, como então a sua resposta resolve o perguntando?

Comment: @ramaral ele quer adicionar um item na lista que está sendo iterada durante a iteração. Da forma que postei é possível reproduzir esse comportamento com o `Iterator`. A dúvida não está clara se ele quer, de fato, fazer funcionar mexendo na lista ou se quer fazer funcionar por outras formas. Se ele quiser mexer na lista, de fato, a resposta não é satisfatória. Se não, a resposta se aplica

Comment: O que você propõe não é muito diferente do que ele tem. Se o erro é por causa de mexer na lista o melhor é usar um `for` tradicional em vez do `foreach`

Comment: Entendi. Com tudo, essa solução funcionou para mim em situações semelhantes. Caso acredite ter uma solução melhor, fique á vontade para postar.

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço aos comentários mas me baseando em alguns mesmo eu pensei nessa lógica, aceito críticas se cometi algum erro mas agora está funcionando uma vez que eu ordeno as listas para que os valores batam certinho. Fiz nessa estrutura uma vez que ambas as listas possuem valores iguais aí eu só complemento a 2 com os faltantes:

```
private void houveAlteracao(Long id) {
        try {
            Objeto objeto = service.find(id);
            objeto.setEventos(JsfUtils.ordenarListaEventosPorHora(objeto.getEventos()));
            Objeto obj = popularObjeto(objeto.getCodigo());
            obj.setEventos(JsfUtils.ordenarListaEventosPorHora(obj.getEventos()));
            if (obj.getEventos().size() > objeto.getEventos().size()) {
                int contador = obj.getEventos().size() - objeto.getEventos().size();
                int inicioIndice = obj.getEventos().size() - contador;
                for (int i = inicioIndice; i < obj.getEventos().size(); i++) {
                    Evento evento = obj.getEventos().get(i);
                    evento.setObjeto(objeto);
                    if (evento.getDestino() != null) {
                        evento.getDestino().setEvento(evento);
                    }
                    objeto.getEventos().add(evento);
                }
                service.update(objeto);
                pesquisar();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```