# Listar dados num dataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Acredito que este método do `dao` que não deve estar correto.

**MÉTODO DAO**

```
public List <Campeonato> listarTodos() {

        try {
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            Query query = manager.createNamedQuery("Campeonato.listarTodos", Campeonato.class);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List <Campeonato> campeonatos = query.getResultList();
            for (Campeonato campeonato : campeonatos) {
                campeonato.setId(campeonato.getId());
                campeonato.setNome(campeonato.getNome());
                campeonatos.add(campeonato);
                Iterator <Campeonato> iterator = campeonatos.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                campeonato = iterator.next();
                }
            } 
            return campeonatos;
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }
```

**MEU BEAN**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import dao.CampeonatoDao;

import model.Campeonato;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CampeonatoBean {

    private Campeonato campeonato;
    private List <Campeonato> campeonatos;

    public CampeonatoBean() {

        campeonato = new Campeonato();
    }
    public void salvar() throws Exception {

        CampeonatoDao campeonatoDao = new CampeonatoDao();
        campeonatoDao.salvar(campeonato);
    }

    public void deletar() throws Exception {

        CampeonatoDao campeonatoDao = new CampeonatoDao();
        campeonatoDao.deletar(campeonato);
    }

    public List <Campeonato> listarCampeonatos()  {

        CampeonatoDao campeonatoDao = new CampeonatoDao();
         campeonatos = campeonatoDao.listarTodos();
         return campeonatos;
    }

    public Campeonato getCampeonato() {
        return campeonato;
    }

    public void setCampeonato(Campeonato campeonato) {
        this.campeonato = campeonato;
    }

    public List<Campeonato> getCampeonatos() {
        return campeonatos;
    }

    public void setCampeonatos(List<Campeonato> campeonatos) {
        this.campeonatos = campeonatos;
    }
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<h:form> 
<p:fieldset> <br/>

<p:panelGrid columns="3" > 
<p:outputLabel value="CAMPEONATO: " /> 
<p:inputText  value="#{campeonatoBean.campeonato.nome}" />
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="SALVAR" action="#{campeonatoBean.salvar}"/>
</p:panelGrid> <br/>

<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="LISTAR" action="#{campeonatoBean.listarCampeonatos}" />

<p:dataTable value="#{campeonatoBean.campeonatos}" var="campeonato" resizableColumns="true" >
<f:facet name="header">
<p:outputLabel value="LISTA DE CAMPEONATOS" />
</f:facet>
<p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{campeonato.id}" >
<h:outputText value="#{campeonato.id}" />
</p:column>     
<p:column headerText="CAMPEONATO" sortBy="#{campeonato.nome}" >
<h:outputText value="#{campeonato.nome}" />
</p:column>     
<p:column >
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="EXCLUIR" action="#{campeonatoBean}"/>          
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>

</p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

**ERRO**

> ```
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Root Cause
>
> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>   javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
>   dao.CampeonatoDao.listarTodos(CampeonatoDao.java:62)
>   controller.CampeonatoBean.listarCampeonatos(CampeonatoBean.java:38)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>   javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
> ```

Comment: Qual o erro ou problema que você esta tendo?

Comment: Quando clico no botão listar... da esse erro
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

e no console mostra...
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{campeonatoBean.listarCampeonatos}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{campeonatoBean.listarCampeonatos}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: dao.CampeonatoDao.listarTodos(CampeonatoDao.java:62) apontando para esse foreach que indiquei q acho q eh nele o erro!

Comment: Poste a stacktrace de erro na pergunta para facilitar

Comment: O problema é que você está fazendo alterações na lista enquanto está percorrendo a mesma. Relacionada: [ConcurrentModificationException como proceder?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194745/concurrentmodificationexception-como-proceder)

Comment: Desculpa o pouco conhecimento, mas onde seria a causa da alteração? Pois não é esse o intuito, quero apenas listar todos os campeonatos no dataTable!

Answer (score 0):

O erro informado é a exceção [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), que de acordo com a documentação, em tradução livre:

> Essa exceção pode ser lançada por métodos que detectaram a modificação
>   simultânea de um objeto quando essa modificação não é permitida.

ou seja, você está alterando um objeto `Campeonato` que está contido na lista `campeonatos`, no método `listarTodos`.

Para o resultado que espera a lista retornada pelo `getResultList()` já é suficiente, ficaria:

```
public List <Campeonato> listarTodos() {
    try {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = manager.createNamedQuery("Campeonato.listarTodos", Campeonato.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui e dou o retorno. Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Henrique MUITO OBRIGADO CARA! RODOU! GRAÇAS A DEUS!
CONTINUE SEMPRE AJUDANDO A GALERA! PRECISAMOS MUITO!
VLW! ABRAÇO!

Comment: Só pra fechar o entendimento... não necessitou do foreach, por causa do namedquery, seria isso neh?